# How do I add an incrementing number to this For each batch script?

Tags: batch-file, foreach

In the below script, I am trying to set the contents of a text file to a friend number. The problem is that `%numb%` is not incrementing as I thought it would. Any idea how to do that? I tried researching however I do not know enough about For Each scripts to know what to do to have both an incrementing number and a for each in the script. Thanks!

```
@echo off
set numb=1
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (list.txt) do  (
   echo Doing junk with %%A and setting it as friend %numb%
   set Friend%numb%=%%A
    set /a numb=%numb%+1
)
set /a %numb%=%numb%-1   
echo there are %numb% Friends
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).
I also changed your counter a bit and implemented another method of incrementing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set numb=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (list.txt) do  (
   set /a numb+=1
   echo Doing junk with %%A and setting it as friend %numb%
   set Friend!numb!=%%A
)
echo there are %numb% Friends:
pause
```

Comment: Aha perfect thank you @Stephan! Forgot that += was an option in batch!

Comment: Should the counter get incremented before the echo and set inside the `FOR`?

Comment: yeah, that seems a bit too modern for batch `;-)`. Thanks @Squashman: that was my intention - changed.